# C# Documentation Generator (no comments or annotations)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, documentation

I am looking for a documentation generator that does not require using comments and/or annotations to the code. Ideally, it would just outline all classes methods, functions, etc... in a manner similar to what is available in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every .NET documentation generator that I'm aware of works fine even without any comments in code. You didn't specify the language. If it's C# or VB .NET, you can try our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (I'm one of its developers). It can generate documentation for every code element. It doesn't matter if it has a comment or not.

Comment: Very nice! That documentation came out just perfect and is exactly what I needed! Thanks!